# Does it make sense to use std::unordered_map<int, int> instead of std::map<int, int>?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, hashmap, unordered-map

Should `std::unordered_map<int, int>` be faster than std::map`? I don't care about order, just fast lookup, so I thought I should use a hashtable. But then I thought maybe it'll try to additionally hash my keys or something like that (which I don't need)?

And a related question: I need to retrieve an `int` value by `int` key. Should I use `unordered_map<int, int>` or `unordered_set<pair<int, int> >` (in which case I'd need to implement hash function for my pair properly)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The difference between a `map<T,K>` and an `unordered_map<T,K>` is that the first implementation relies on a tree while the second relies on an hashmap.

This means that complexities for basic operations (get and set) are logarithmic for a `map` and constant for an `unordered_map`.

There are other aspects in any case: an `unordered_map` may need a rehash when its load factor is reached (and this requires time and can be unpredictable) while a normal `map` doesn't involve such problems. In addition the `unordered_map` implementation could use separated chaining with buckets so if it happens to have many collisions, complexity becomes constant+linear for retrieval of the key.

I'd suggest you to benchmark both structures with some data with a pattern similar to the one you need, that will make your choice.

You don't need to define your own [`hash<int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) for the `unordered_map` as it's already implemented.

Comment: The point is, I'm already supplying the hashmap with hash values (my keys are hashes). Does it make sense?

Comment: No, you are not exactly supplying your hashmap with hash values, unless its capacity is `2<<(sizeof(int)*8)` so that every int value can be mapped to its own cell, but in this case an `int[2<<(sizeof(int)*8]` array would suffice. And problems will be related to caching of the data, not to data structure perfomance anymore.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe : if desired, you can supply your own hash functions to `unordered_map`. Be sure to understand the pitfalls and caveats before doing so, however.